# Problems playing sound in pygame Windows

Tags: python, windows, audio, pygame

I have a little pygame project from a friend, an works in my machine, but in his machine Python throws this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/joaco/Desktop/RETO Starus/PingPong/Play.py", line 174, in
>   
>       main()   File "C:/Users/joaco/Desktop/RETO Starus/PingPong/Play.py", line 151, in main
>       puntos = bola.actualizar(time,pala_jug1, pala_jug2, puntos)   File "C:/Users/joaco/Desktop/RETO Starus/PingPong/Play.py", line 48, in
>   actualizar
>       pygame.mixer.music.load(sonido_pared) pygame.error: Module format not recognized

https://github.com/Starus/PingPongStarus

Comment: Try asking your friend to do a clean install of python and pygame and make sure you both have the same versions.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a mismatch between pygame or python version between yours and your friends computer.

Run following program on both the machines and see if  python and pygame version matches up.

For python 3.x you may have to use `print` with parenthesis.

```
import pygame  
import sys  
print "Python Version=",sys.version  
print "Pygame Version=",pygame.version.ver
```

**Output**

> Python Version= 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
>   Pygame Version= 1.9.1release